# I cannot find javadoc or source files for JDK 8 Update 321 on the net

Tags: java, windows, intellij-idea, javadoc

In the projects in IntelliJ IDEA I am using **JDK 8 Update 321**, but I am missing javadoc or source for the SDK.

OS is Windows 10.

I realy tried, but wasn't able to find either on the internet.

Comment: https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-jdk8-doc-downloads.html

Comment: @ThomasBehr Those are for JDK 8 Update 351

Comment: Why do you specifically need it for Java 8 update 321? Update to the latest Java 8 version and use its documentation.

Comment: @sinclair Does not matter. Public API does not change in patch releases.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel because those are not my personal projects and that specific version of Java is obligatory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javadoc: https://javadl.oracle.com/webapps/download/AutoDL?BundleId=245778_df5ad55fdd604472a86a45a217032c7d

The source should be part of the JDK, search for `src.zip` in your JDK directory.

[How to attach JDK source code to IntelliJ IDEA](https://mkyong.com/java/how-to-attach-jdk-source-code-to-intellij-idea/)

Comment: That download URL is likely to disappear in the next few months.  The URL Thomas Behr provided in comments is likely to be stable in the long term.

Comment: Thank you, only the link is for javadoc, not for source. So attaching it to the SDK in IDEA should be via **Documentation Paths**, not **Sourcepath**.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't know that patch releases don't change the public API, so both Thomas Behr's comment and sinclair's answer are valid.

Only thing to add is that the **javadoc** zip should be included in IntelliJ IDA via *File -> Project Structure -> Platform Settings -> SDKs -> **Documentation Paths** (instead of **Sourcepath**)*.